# irb returning NameError: uninitialized constant Date

Tags: ruby, date, irb, nameerror, uninitialized-constant

ruby-v2.2.3 is supposed to have Date class preloaded into irb, however when I enter...

> Date
>   NameError: uninitialized constant Date
>          from (irb):1
>          from /Users/noah/.rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/irb:11:in `'

Why should I have to `require Date` every single time if it's supposed to be preloaded into 2.2.3?

Comment: You are mistaken. That is not a core class.

Comment: Please show us the reference where Date is preloaded in v2.2.3. The [2.2.3 core page](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/) doesn't show it.

Comment: Gotchya. I was clearly mistaken on that point. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Date isn't listed as a [core class in v2.2.3](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/) or the current [Ruby v2.3.1 core-classes](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/), but Time is. Here's some IRb output:

```
$ irb -f
irb(main):001:0> Date.class
NameError: uninitialized constant Date
Did you mean?  Data
  from (irb):1
  from /Users/ttm/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0> Time.class
=> Class
irb(main):003:0> Time.methods(false)
=> [:at, :now, :utc, :gm, :local, :mktime]
```

That is a limited subset of Time's methods though:

```
irb(main):002:0> require 'time'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> Time.methods(false)
=> [:at, :now, :utc, :gm, :local, :mktime, :parse, :zone_offset, :strptime, :rfc2822, :rfc822, :httpdate, :xmlschema, :iso8601]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you say `Date` is preloaded? It's not a core class, it's part of the stdlib so it needs to be required. `Time` is a core class instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do the following in the beginning of your file:

```
require 'Date'
```

Comment: So upper case `Date` gave me an error, that's why I posted [this separate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74532788/4575793). I hope, that's fine with you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, (and as [Ursus said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39149796/4575793)), `Date` is not preloaded.

Attention: So [Tilec suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74172654/4575793) to just load the library at the beginning of the file, which gave me (Not sure if that is true in general): this gave me `LoadError: cannot load such file -- Date`. Trying `gem install Date` gives me

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'Date' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: date
```

**Solution:** So I'm proposing to correct to lower case:

```
require 'date'
```